# Regex to find name in sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have some sentence like

1:

> "RLB shows Oubre Jr. (WAS) legally ties up Nurkic (POR), and a held
>   ball is correctly called."

2:

> "Nurkic (POR) maintains legal
>   guarding position and makes incidental contact with Wall (WAS) that
>   does not affect his driving shot attempt."

I need to use Python regex to find the name "Oubre Jr." ,"Nurkic" and "Nurkic", "Wall".

```
p = r'\s*(\w+?)\s[(]'
```

use this pattern, 
I can find "['Nurkic', 'Wall']", but in sentence 1, I just can find ['Nurkic'], missed "Oubre Jr."

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

`(?:[A-Z][a-z][\s\.a-z]*)+(?=\s\()`

`|-----Main Pattern-----|`

---

**Details**:

- `(?:)` - Creates a non-capturing group
- `[A-Z]` - Captures 1 uppercase letter
- `[a-z]` - Captures 1 lowercase letter
- `[\s\.a-z]*` - Captures spaces (`' '`), periods (`'.'`) or lowercase letters 0+ times
- `(?=\s\()` - Captures the main pattern if it is only followed by `' ('` string

---

```
str = '''RLB shows Oubre Jr. (WAS) legally ties up Nurkic (POR), and a held ball is correctly called. 

Nurkic (POR) maintains legal guarding position and makes incidental contact with Wall (WAS) that does not affect his driving shot attempt.'''

res = re.findall( r'(?:[A-Z][a-z][\s\.a-z]*)+(?=\s\()', str )

print(res)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@RahulVerma8/OvalRequiredAdvance?language=python3

Match: https://regex101.com/r/OsLTrY/1

Comment: Since I will have sentence like "McCollum (POR) has a hand momentarily on Beal's (WAS) arm but does not affect his FOM off ball."  . So First I use "re.sub(r'\'s*','',test_str)" , then re.findall( r'([A-Z][a-z][\s\.a-z]*)+(?=\s\()', test_str) . Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
line = "RLB shows Oubre Jr (WAS) legally ties up Nurkic (POR), and a held ball is correctly called."
results = re.findall( r'([A-Z][\w+'](?: [JS][r][.]?)?)(?= \([A-Z]+\))', line, re.M|re.I)
print(results)

['Oubre Jr', 'Nurkic']
```

The above logic will attempt to match one name, beginning with a capital letter, which is possibly followed by either the suffix `Jr.` or `Sr.`, which in turn is followed by a `([A-Z]+)` term.

Comment: seems the code coloring does not handle inline ' that well :/ nice solution

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but like sentences.  
3:"Oubre Jr. (WAS) makes contact to Aminu's (POR) head during rebounding."  
4:"RAR shows Aminu (POR) wraps Porter Jr. (WAS) around the waist and dislodges him, affecting his ability to grab the rebound."  
5:"McCollum (POR) has a hand momentarily on Beal's (WAS) arm but does not affect his FOM off ball."  
Still will miss "Oubre Jr" "Porter Jr" and "Beal".   
Could you help?

Comment: Adding additional requirements in comments to an individual answer. Just accept an answer and ask a new question if at this point you find that you need something else than you originally asked for.

Comment: @tripleee Are suggesting that it's _not_ polite to generate a hideous trail of comments which don't really add any value to the original question? :-P

Comment: If you really want to discuss this further, maybe post a question on [meta]

Answer (score 0):

You need a pattern that you can match - for your sentence you cou try to match things before (XXX) and include a list of possible "suffixes" to include as well - you would need to extract them from your sources

```
import re

suffs = ["Jr."] # append more to list

rsu   = r"(?:"+"|".join(suffs)+")? ?"

# combine with suffixes
regex = r"(\w+ "+rsu+")\(\w{3}\)"

test_str = "RLB shows Oubre Jr. (WAS) legally ties up Nurkic (POR), and a held ball is correctly called. Nurkic (POR) maintains legal guarding position and makes incidental contact with Wall (WAS) that does not affect his driving shot attempt."

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

names = []
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches,1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        names.extend(match.groups(groupNum))

print(names)
```

Output:

```
['Oubre Jr.', 'Nurkic ', 'Nurkic ', 'Wall ']
```

This should work as long as you do not have Names with non-`\w` in them. If you need to adapt the regex, use https://regex101.com/r/pRr9ZU/1 as starting point.

---

Explanation:

- `r"(?:"+"|".join(suffs)+")? ?"` --> all items in the list `suffs` are strung together via `|` (OR) as non grouping (?:...) and made optional followed by optional space.
- `r"(\w+ "+rsu+")\(\w{3}\)"`  --> the regex looks for any word characters followed by optional `suffs` group we just build, followed by literal `(` then three word characters followed by another literal `)`